# Update build number of a pipeline with respect to another pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, cicd, build-pipeline

I have a build pipeline, say, Pipeline 1 whose build number is in `$(Year:yy)$(DayOfYear)$(Rev:.r)` format. I've created a copy of Pipeline 1, say Pipeline 2.

Now, when I push anything to those pipelines, build number is independent of each other, obviously. So, it might be possible that both pipelines have the same build number. Now, I'm looking for a solution to increment the revision of Pipeline 1 w.r.t Pipeline 2 and vice-versa so that the build number doesn't overlap. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the out-of-box perspective, no. You have to add your custom logic (with powershell or python) to the following:

1. Get the last builds: [Builds - List REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1) or [az pipelines build list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/pipelines/build?view=azure-cli-latest#az-pipelines-build-list)
2. Generate your build number
3. Update a current build number: [UpdateBuildNumber: Override the automatically generated build number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#updatebuildnumber-override-the-automatically-generated-build-number)